# Unable to ssh in beagle bone black

Tags: ssh, aws-cloud9

I wanted to install pip onto beagle bone black,and I tried this:

```
  /usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u pool.ntp.org
    opkg update && opkg install python-pip python-setuptools
```

Then it threw errors, but unfortunately, I didn't log that errors. It was occurred a week ago and wasn't solved yet. I wanted to solve it now and I tried connect by ssh,but I failed.

When I ping to beagle bone, it responds, and Cloud9 IDE is working too, but not ssh.

I don't think this is serious problem since I can connect to beagle bone by other methods: Cloud9 or so.
However, to use python on beagle bone, I need to connect by ssh.

Before trying to update and install python-pip, I could connect by ssh.

Do you have any ideas to solve this connection problem?

**note**

- I use default OS: Angstrom
- I don't use SD card.
- Host PC is mac, OS.X 10.9
- Connect by USB serial

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233516/cannot-connect-to-beagle-bone-black) but this wasn't helpful.

I could connect by GateOne SSH client, but still unable to connect from terminal.

Comment: I suggest this Q about Angstrom Linux configuration be moved to Superuser.com.

Comment: You can use the "flag" link to ask the site moderators to move the question. (or you could delete the Q from here before posting a duplicate at SU)

Comment: I solved this problem and I wrote the method here:
[unable-to-connect-beagle-bone-black-by-ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897749/unable-to-connect-beagle-bone-black-by-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ssh server(default: dropbear) isn't running. (Re)start it using:

```
/etc/init.d/dropbear start
```

Check this page by the element14 community about probably the same problem:
http://www.element14.com/community/community/knode/single-board_computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2013/05/22/some-quick-start-things-to-do-for-developing-on-the-bbb